# Conditional sign out in Rails app using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session, devise

I'm creating a rails app where users log in and look at various pages. Some are private, and others are public. If a user signs out while viewing a private page, he should be redirected to root_path. If a user signs out while viewing a public page, he should be redirected to the same page (which will be rendered slightly differently now that he is signed out).

I want to do this with a conditional statement in the after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope) method within my application_controller. The problem is that the @page variable, which is normally accessed from the pages_controller file, is nil and/or not available in this scope. What is the best way to access this variable (the last loaded page) from a different controller and after the session has been destroyed?

Thanks.

Comment: Follow-up question: Is there some way I can pass a reference to the page into the method using the resource_or_scope parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep track of the last page in session variable and add before filter to keep it up to date in the pages controller.

```
session[:last_page_visited] = @page
```

You also have access to `request.referrer` which will give you the URL of the page where they signed out from. Not sure if you can determine private/public from that, maybe using regex?

Comment: Thanks man! Ended up using request.referrer with some regex, because the session is destroyed after the user signs out.